# Induction with a Base Case that does not Hold

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let P(n) mean $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i =\frac{({2n+1})^2}{8}$.

Prove that for all positive integers k, $P(k)$ $\rightarrow$ $P(k+1)$.

**Base Case** that I obtained:

$P(1) = \frac{({2(1)+1})^2}{8} = \frac{9}{8} \neq 1$ (LHS)

So, the base case $P(1)$ does not hold.

This means that $P(k)$ does not hold either, right? Which means that $P(k)$ is false. However, the given statement states that $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$, and $P(k)$ being false will automatically means $P(k+1)$ is true.

So is the conclusion: for all positive numbers $k$, $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$ is true. Even though the base case and $P(k)$ failed?

This seems like a weak proof, so how can I improve the proof?

Comment: You have a mistake in your proof. $P(1)$ being false does mean that $P(1)\to P(2)$ is true, no matter the truth value of $P(2)$. However, this tells you nothing about $P(2)$ so you cannot conclude *anything* about $P(2)\to P(3)$ or about $P(3)$, etc.

Comment: Just because $P(1)$ is false doesn't mean that $P(2)$ is also false. In fact, it is true that $P(1) \implies P(2)$, but that doesn't help you in proving the induction step. In general, a conditional statement is true under all conditions except when the hypothesis is true but the conclusion is false. Conditional statements are true in all other circumstances, including ones where the hypothesis is false.

Comment: Your title has a hign degree of attraction whatever the content of the question !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P(1)$ being false does not imply that $P(2)$ is false.

Take a known true example: let $Q(n)$ be the statement

$$\sum_{k=1}^n n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

We know this holds for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$, and adopting the convention that empty sums are zero, can show that it's true for $n=0$ and $-1$, but it's false for $n=-2$. But obviously $Q(-2)$ being false is not affecting whether $Q(-1)$ is true or not.

What you are being asked, in fact, is not even to do the induction or to use a base case -- you are meant to be specifically showing the hypothetical induction step. The induction step alone doesn't mean anything without a base case, though -- it's nice that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$, but if you don't have a $P(1)$ or $P(10)$ or $P(10^{10^{100}})$ to jump off that from, then you have nothing.

Showing that $P(1)$ doesn't work just means that $k=1$ is not the starting point for your induction. Maybe it's $2$ or $3$ or $\text{TREE}(3)$, who knows.  But it's, at this moment, an entirely irrelevant question.

> **The key takeaway** is that you should look strictly at the question being asked: assume $k$ is a number such that $P(k)$ holds, and show that $P(k+1)$ holds.

---

This can be summarized differently from the formal logic standpoint: when is $P \implies Q$ true? If you fill out a truth table, or consider this the definition, you have

[image]

Hence, even if $P(1)$ is itself a false statement, that actually means (as far as we care) "$P(1) \implies P(2)$" is a true statement, even if $P(2)$ itself is false!

---

Ultimately, the goal is to show, then, assuming $P(k)$ is true, that $P(k+1)$ is true. (If $P(k)$ is false, we're done.) We have

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i &= (k+1) + \sum_{i=1}^{k} i\\
&= k+1 + \frac{(2k+1)^2}{8} \tag{$P(k)$ is  true} \\
&= \frac{8k+8+(2k+1)^2}{8}\\
&= \frac{4k^2 + 4k + 1 + 8k + 8}{8}\\
&= \frac{4k^2 + 12k + 9}{8}\\
&= \frac{(2k+3)^2}{8}\\
&= \frac{(2(k+1)+1)^2}{8}
\end{align*}$$

giving the desired result.

Comment: Excellent answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, for every positive integer $n,$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{({2n+1})^2}{8} - \frac18. \tag1$$

So you really have two ways to prove that $P(k) \implies P(k+1).$

One way is to do the usual algebraic manipulations on $P(k)$
("usual" in the sense that they are similar to the manipulations by which we would prove actual formulas for sums of consecutive integers, consecutive squares, consecutive odd integers, etc.),
from which $P(k + 1)$ will follow.
You already have one answer showing this.

Another way is to prove the two equations tagged $(1),$ above,
from which you can conclude that $P(k)$ is false for every positive integer $k.$
From that fact it immediately follows (by the definition of implication) that
$P(k) \implies P(k+1).$

What I wonder is whether the problem was stated as intended.
The formula that you were given is a false statement,
but there is a very similar-looking true statement:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \left\lfloor \frac{({2n+1})^2}{8} \right\rfloor. $$